# Rgb 565 Pdf to Image

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to convert a PDF page to an image, to create thumbnails. This is the code that I am using:

```cs
PdfRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(GetSeekableFileDescriptor(filePath));

var appDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
string directoryPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDirectory, "thumbnailsTemp", System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName));

if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);

    int pageCount = pdfRenderer.PageCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
    {
        Page page = pdfRenderer.OpenPage(i);
        Android.Graphics.Bitmap bmp = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(page.Width, page.Height, Android.Graphics.Bitmap.Config.Rgb565 or Argb8888);
        page.Render(bmp, null, null, PdfRenderMode.ForDisplay);

        try
        {
            using (FileStream output = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileName + "Thumbnails" + i + ".png"), FileMode.Create))
            {
                bmp.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, output);
            }

            page.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO -- GERER CETTE EXPEXPTION
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    return directoryPath;
}
```

I tried with `ARGB 8888` and that was a success. But the rendering time was too slow for big PDF files. This is why I tried to improve it by changing the format to `RGB 565`. But my app is crashing with this Execption:

> Unsuported pixel format

Any idea to fix this, or how to render a PDF to a bitmap faster? I was looking on google but didn't find a solution related to my code.

***UPDATE***

I did this but know, my app is crashing at this line of code :

```
await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                bytes = page.AsPNG(72);
            });
```

My class :

```
public async Task<string> GetBitmaps(string filePath)
    {

        //TODO -- WORK ON THIS
        PdfRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(GetSeekableFileDescriptor(filePath));

        var appDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
        string directoryPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDirectory, "thumbnailsTemp", System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName));

        var stream = new MemoryStream();

        using (Stream resourceStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            resourceStream.CopyTo(stream);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < pdfRenderer.PageCount; i++)
        {
            TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer.Page page = new TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer.Page(stream, i);

            byte[] bytes = null;
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                bytes = page.AsPNG(72);
            });

            using (FileStream output = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileName + "Thumbnails" + i + ".png"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                output.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }

        return directoryPath;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could draw a PDF page in app by converting a PDF page to a bitmap,here the PDF document itself is embedded as a resource.

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var stream = new MemoryStream();
using (Stream resourceStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("DrawPdf.Android.tiger.pdf"))
{
  resourceStream.CopyTo(stream);
}
Page page = new Page(stream, 0);

// render PDF Page object to a Bitmap
byte[] bytes = null;
await Task.Run(() =>
{
   bytes = page.AsPNG(72);
});
Bitmap bmp = global::Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Comment: Ok I will try this, but do you thing that saving bitmap as jpeg Will increase the rendering time ? Thank you

Comment: I didn't found The class Page that u are using with this constructor : Page(Stream, index) I was looking on google and I only found 2 class : Android.Graphics.Pdf.PdfDocument and Android.Graphics.Pdf.PdfRenderer.

Comment: @guizmo Sorry I forgot to say it work with `TallComponents.PDFRasterizer4` nuget package,you should install it.

Comment: unfortunatly the package isn't compatible with MonoAndroid V:9.0 :(

Comment: I didn't try it in 9.0, you could try `XFINIUM.PDF` library if it's not compatible,you could google it.

Comment: I understand my problem... I was trying to install : **TallComponents.PDFRasterizer4** note the  **TallComponents.PDFRasterizer**. But know I have a new problem, check the update above.